# Db Design of a Room Booking System

Tags: database-design, erd

I plan on building a web based room booking application for meeting rooms at a company. The requirements are not set in stone and are pretty much left to me, as long as these core ones are met:

1. Users can view monthly schedule for meeting room, so see what days and times there are bookings for a particular room.
2. Users can book a meeting room
3. Users can edit,delete a booking once made.
4. Receptionists have power to cancel bookings, even though they were not the ones that made them.

If I have missed any obvious ones, please point them out.

So with the above in mind, I have come up with the following ERD.

[image: erd room booking]

Can you see any obvious issues with the above ERD? I have gone through the above scenarios / requirements, and I believe the above design satisfies them all, but it is possible that I am very much mistaken (has happened before).

Any help and feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So far nothing prevents multiple people from booking one and the same room for one and the same day.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov People are allowed to do that (e.g. book Picaso Room for 10:00, then make another booking for Picaso room for 15:00)

Comment: Can you have two meetings going on in the same room at the same time? If not, how will your design prevent it?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov I thought one would check that through code before attempting to write to Database. How would you prevent that at the Db level?

Comment: Сan you show me the final Room Booking System ER-diagram?

Answer (score 2):

How do you know how long a room is booked for?  Your model indicates when a booking starts, but when does it end?

Also, your ERD shows foreign keys from `BOOKING` to `USER` and `ROOM` but these columns aren't acknowledged in your `BOOKING` table.  Some other answers have interpreted that as the columns being missing.  You should be explicit in your diagram to avoid confusion (or add the FK columns if you missed them!)

Comment: Good catch about the end of a booking @JoelBrown. Thanks. As for showing the FK columns ... I use Entity Framework, and it handles it for me, but since this is about Db Design, I have gone ahead and updated my ERD. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Wiggler Jtag's recommendation.  Here's why:

Describe the relationship between `USER` and `ROOM`. If it is "a user can have zero, one, or more rooms booked" then you have a one to many relationship.

Describe the relationship between `ROOM` and `USER`.  If it is "a room can have zero, one, or more bookings by a user" then this is also a one to many relationship.

Using normalization, you would define an intersection table.  You have this defined as `BOOKING`.  `BOOKING` should contain the PKs (primary keys) from `USER` and `ROOM`.  PKs should be unique.  The `BOOKING` entity would have attributes `USER_ID`, `ROOM_ID`, `DATETIME`, and `TITLE`.

If you wish to ensure that only one USER can book a ROOM for a particular `DATETIME`, then you can add a unique concatenated index on `BOOKING` of `ROOM_ID`, `DATETIME`.  This will ensure that there will be only one row for a room at a particular time.

Primary index (or unique index) on the `PKs` of `USER` and `ROOM` will also ensure that you don't have more than one row per user or one row per room.

Comment: The relationship is: "a user can have zero, one, or more bookings for the same or different rooms, as long as time does not overlap."

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the current design is that we are unable to uniquely identify which room a user has booked if he has booked more than 1 room .

To solve the problem , we should add another column : **Room Number** to the TABLE ROOM

This allows the **composite key**  : Room Number& ID to form a **primary key** which would uniquely identify any booking made by a user.

The Room Number & ID would be foreign keys in the TABLE BOOKING

Comment: Either I am going mad, or missing something so obvious that I'll hate myself for it later, but I just can not see how "we are unable to uniquely identify which room a user has booked when he has booked more than 1 room" :/ As far as I can tell, the diagram allows this easily.

Comment: @Ciwan Assuming a user books 2 room , how would you identify which 2 rooms he has booked without ID

Comment: You will get a list of the user's bookings, and through that you can tell what booking has what room .. no!?